# An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation While running a command "mvn -Pfitnesselocal test"

Tags: javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, unsupported-class-version

This is my error log

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.4.1:javadoc (default) on project WorkFlow: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: 
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - error: Class nl.praegus.doclets.FixtureDocGenerator is not a valid doclet.
[ERROR]   Note: As of JDK 13, the com.sun.javadoc API is no longer supported.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc @options @packages
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/home/pando-remo/Pando_repo/automation/workflow/src/main/resources/META-INF/apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I clone a repo from git. And installed maven and my java version is 18.0.2
When i try to run fitneese in my local, I used the command 'mvn -Pfitnesselocal test'
that time this error came, instead of build passed port 4000 started.

Thanks in Advance